# Having an error in django's raw SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, django

I got error

> (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'radians(151.20711)) + sin(radians(-33.86714)) * sin(radians(latitude)))) AS dist' at line 1")

when I ran below code.

```
query = '''SELECT id, longitude, latitude, (6378 * acos(cos(radians(-33.86714)) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) – radians(151.20711)) + sin(radians(-33.86714)) * sin(radians(latitude)))) AS distance 
FROM ads_suburb HAVING distance < 10 ORDER BY distance;'''
surrounded_suburbs = Suburb.objects.raw(query)
for suburb in surrounded_suburbs:
    print(suburb.id)
```

Where do I need to fix?

**Updated**

I tried another approach, but still getting **same** error.

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('''SELECT id, longitude, latitude, (6378 * acos(cos(radians(-33.86714)) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) – radians(151.20711)) + sin(radians(-33.86714)) * sin(radians(latitude)))) AS distance FROM ads_suburb HAVING distance < 10 ORDER BY distance;''')
ids = [row[0] for row in cursor.fetchall()]
print(ids)
```

Comment: The expression for `distance` appears to be balanced.  Are you sure that this code is causing the actual error?

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm misunderstanding, but you mean there is no wrong in this code?

Comment: It means that I don't see any syntax problem with your code.  But, someone else might, so leave this question up a bit longer.

Comment: Please post the actual code: error message contains aliases whereas code sample does not.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry for posting previous error message. I modified it.

Comment: I'm not sure about MySql, but in general HAVING can be applied after GROUP BY only. As well as column alias cannot be used in WHERE at the same level.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution finally.
It was because of "–" inside query.
I changed "–" to "-", it works.